# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express - error "Incorrect syntax near '<'."

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is my query which is to get data:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ( adherernt.matricule )
       ,adherernt.section
       ,adherernt.nom
       ,adherernt.prenom
       ,adherernt.datenaissance
       ,YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(adherernt.datenaissance) AS Age
       ,SUM(cotisation.totalmurcas) AS TotalMurcas
       ,SUM(cotisation.totalfasas) AS TotalFasas
       ,0
       ,adherernt.modepaiement
       ,adherernt.anneepaiement
       ,adherernt.statut
       ,adherernt.ville
       ,adherernt.numcompte
    FROM certificats_vie
       ,adherernt
       ,cotisation
    WHERE (
            certificats_vie.datedebut <= '08/01/2014'
            AND certificats_vie.datefin > '2014-01-08' )
        AND certificats_vie.matricule = adherernt.matricule
        AND adherernt.matricule = cotisation.matricule
    GROUP BY adherernt.matricule
       ,adherernt.section
       ,adherernt.nom
       ,adherernt.prenom
       ,adherernt.datenaissance
       ,adherernt.modepaiement
       ,adherernt.anneepaiement
       ,adherernt.statut
       ,adherernt.ville
       ,adherernt.numcompte
```

but I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '<'

Kindly solve my problem, thanks in advance.

This my code:

```
public void InsertRentesBis()
{
    string reqSql = "select DISTINCT(adherernt.Matricule) , adherernt.Section , adherernt.Nom, adherernt.Prenom , adherernt.DateNaissance ,"
                              +"YEAR(GETDATE())- YEAR(adherernt.DateNaissance) as Age , SUM(cotisation.TotalMurcas) as TotalMurcas ,"
                              + "SUM(cotisation.TotalFasas) as TotalFasas, 0 , adherernt.ModePaiement, adherernt.AnneePaiement, adherernt.Statut, adherernt.Ville, adherernt.NumCompte"
                              +"from certificats_vie, adherernt, cotisation"
                              +"where (certificats_vie.Datedebut<='08/01/2014' and certificats_vie.Datefin >'2014-01-08')"
                              +"and certificats_vie.Matricule = adherernt.Matricule and adherernt.Matricule=cotisation.Matricule"
                              +"group by adherernt.Matricule , adherernt.Section , adherernt.Nom, adherernt.Prenom , adherernt.DateNaissance ,"
                              + "adherernt.ModePaiement, adherernt.AnneePaiement, adherernt.Statut, adherernt.Ville, adherernt.NumCompte";

    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MURCASFASAS;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(reqSql, conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();


        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OK");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With all the edits that have taken place, it's not at all clear that the query in the question as it is now still has the problem described. Also, this question was tagged MySQL (already removed); if you actually do anything with MySQL, can you explain what?

Comment: Can't see any syntax error. Are you executing in SSMS? Did you have any text selected?

Comment: BTW Not an explanation for the error but why `DISTINCT ( adherernt.matricule )`? `DISTINCT` applies to the whole select list.

Comment: The SQL syntax ok but a syntax error on < might be because you are inserting this into an HTML/XML thing where the < is interpreted as a tag. Is this query working in the SQL prompt or not at all ? Note also that your date formats differ within the same query and that "adherent" is wrongly spelled.

Comment: I'm guessing your locality setting shows date in `dd/mm/yyyy` or `yyyy-mm-dd` format? In your queries you should stick to one format not to confuse your self and others. By accident someone might switch `mm` and `dd`

Comment: @EricDarchis - How sure are you on the spelling? Are you fluent in Portugese or whatever the column names are in?

Comment: @MartinSmith looks like italian, its not portuguese for sure.

Comment: @MartinSmith The other names look like French to me, but I'm pretty sure "adherernt" is not a word in French either. "adhérent" is.

Comment: @hvd - Yes agree. I randomly googled "Murcas" and first hit was Portugal but agree looks like French!

Comment: Your query as posted parses just fine. I have taken the liberty of re-writing your query slightly: http://pastebin.com/p6ngxq0W

Comment: yes I execute in SSMS with all the selected text it works well. but when I use the same query in my C # code, I get the error...

Comment: @user3275259 Then what you're using in C# isn't the same query. Your C# version, not part of the question, has a typo somewhere.

Comment: So you need to show the C# code that you are executing then. It can't be executing the same thing.

Comment: @MartinSmith I confirm it is French and it is spelled Adhérent which means "member". It corresponds to the column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be sure ans add spaces to either the beginning or end (or both) of strings when you concatenate:

```
                          + "SUM(cotisation.TotalFasas) as TotalFasas, 0 , adherernt.ModePaiement, adherernt.AnneePaiement, adherernt.Statut, adherernt.Ville, adherernt.NumCompte"
                          +"from certificats_vie, adherernt, cotisation"
                          +"where (certificats_vie.Datedebut<='08/01/2014' and certificats_vie.Datefin >'2014-01-08')"
```

will give you (scroll right to see the problem)

```
SUM(cotisation.TotalFasas) as TotalFasas, 0 , adherernt.ModePaiement, adherernt.AnneePaiement, adherernt.Statut, adherernt.Ville, adherernt.NumComptefrom certificats_vie, adherernt, cotisationwhere (certificats_vie.Datedebut<='08/01/2014' and certificats_vie.Datefin >'2014-01-08')"
                                                                                                                                                     ^-- here (keep scrolling)                  ^-- and here
```

When parsing, the first problem the compiler comes across is a `<=` in a place where it doesn't know what to do with it.

Change your C# code to

```
                          + " SUM(cotisation.TotalFasas) as TotalFasas, 0 , adherernt.ModePaiement, adherernt.AnneePaiement, adherernt.Statut, adherernt.Ville, adherernt.NumCompte "
                          + " from certificats_vie, adherernt, cotisation "
                          + " where (certificats_vie.Datedebut<='08/01/2014' and certificats_vie.Datefin >'2014-01-08') "
```